# React Native Plaid Integration

Tags: react-native, expo, plaid

I am trying to build a React Native app using expo. I want to integrate Plaid in the app for transactions. How can I integrate Plaid in the app? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plaid library `npm i react-native-plaid-link`
Here is [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-plaid-link)

Comment: Yes thanks! I was using this before also, but somehow the module version was not compatible with the webview. So I reinstalled and downgraded it. Now its working.